# 3D Java programming tutorial isn't working

Tags: java, user-interface, render, pixel

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iH1xpfOBN6M   I've followed this tutorial up to episode four and where his window has pixels in it, mine is completely blank. I want to know whether anyone with experience with 3d programming in eclipse can see if there is something that doesn't look right to you.

Display:

```
package com.mine.minefrost;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.minefrost.graphics.Render;
import com.minefrost.graphics.Screen;

public class Display extends Canvas {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final int WIDTH = 800;
public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
public static final String TITLE = "Minefrost Pre-Alpha 0.01";

private Thread thread;
private Screen screen;
private BufferedImage img;
private Render render;
private boolean running = false;
private int[] pixels;

public Display() {
        screen = new Screen(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        pixels = ((DataBufferInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
}

private void start() {
    if (running) 
        return;
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread();
    thread.start(); 
    }

private void stop() {
    if (!running) return;
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private void run() {
    while (running) {
        tick();
        render();

    }
}

private void tick() {

}

private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    screen.render();

    for (int i = 0; i<WIDTH * HEIGHT; i++) {
        pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img,  0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display game = new Display();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(game);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setTitle(TITLE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    game.start();
}

}
```

Render:

```
package com.minefrost.graphics;

public class Render {
public final int width;
public final int height;
public final int[] pixels;

public Render(int width,int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    pixels = new int[width * height];
}

public void draw(Render render, int xOffset, int yOffset) {
    for (int y = 0; y < render.height; y++) {
        int yPix = y + yOffset;
        for (int x = 0; x < render.width; x++) {
            int xPix = x + xOffset;

            pixels[xPix+yPix*width] = render.pixels[x+y*render.width];
        }

    }
}

}
```

Screen:

```
package com.minefrost.graphics;

import java.util.Random;

public class Screen extends Render {

private Render test;

public Screen(int width, int height) {
    super(width, height);
    Random random = new Random();
    test = new Render(256, 256);
    for (int i = 0; i <256*256; i++) {
        test.pixels[i] = random.nextInt();

    }

}

public void render() {
    draw(test, 0, 0);       
}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Almost nobody writes 3D games without library nowadays. It's a good exercise for learning purpose to understand some basic principles of computer graphics but at the end, you get a terribly slow first person shooter like this one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/linkinland/ Good luck.

Comment: You can still make decent 3d games without a library, it just makes it quicker and easier if you do use one but you can still make a perfectly fine game all you need is time. Although I am doing this so I can learn so when I actually do create a 3d game I probably will use a library.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "decent". At first, if you don't use a library, you implicitly have to write your own one and actually this is what this guy does in his tutorial. If you want to spend your time in writing a game (not a library), use at least one library. Secondly, if you don't use a library, you will probably NOT access hardware acceleration because reinventing JogAmp (JOGL, JOAL, JOCL) would be too hard. Then, you will use software rendering which is very difficult to implement efficiently.

Comment: Therefore, if you want to make a "decent" game playable even with a middle end CPU with a "decent" frame rate (at least greater or equal to 20), you will have to draw only a few simple meshes and in low resolution like in d3caster: http://www.stahlworks.com/dev/index.php?tool=d3caster I know only one (discontinued) engine with an efficient software renderer, it's 3DzzD and even an expert in 3D computer graphics would take several years to write another one as fast as this one. I don't use LibGDX currently but you can create a working blueprint of a 3D game in a few hours by using its examples.

Comment: a map with an infinite render distance is running at 70fps on my laptop and this laptop is 4 years old. the graphics are working perfectly and its all going great, without a use of a library.

Comment: There is no "infinite" render distance, the computers manage finite numbers and simulate the infinite. The frustum has a near plane and a far plane, the far plane can't be at an "infinite" distance, it's a basic principle of computer graphics. Moreover, you don't indicate the complexity of your scene, you don't tell how much polygons are effectively rendered, you don't indicate the resolution of your rendering and you give no mean to reproduce your experience. Render 1 500 000 triangles with a resolution of 1920*1080 in full screen mode and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main method in the Display class needs to call `game.run()`. With that in, you get a display of some random pixel 'snow' in the top left corner. I'm not sure if that's what you wanted, but it's what happens!

Another minor point is that the reference to the `Render` class in `Display` is unused. Also, it's odd that `stop()` and `run()` are private.

Comment: quick question, how would one do this? I tried what i thought you meant and it didn't work.

Comment: never mind i figured it out, had to implement runnable, change `private void run` to `public` and change `thread = new thread();` to `thread = new thread(this);`